# How to hide multiple list object in one report page based on list data

Tags: cognos-10, cognos-bi

How can I hide multiple list object based on if each list iteam have data or no data. I am not want to hide any column in the list, I want to hide entire list in the report page. In case of if report page have more than one list objects then how can I perform this operation in Cognos Report Studio?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The list object itself has a property for determining the behavior when no data is available. The default is to display the string "No Data Available", but you can change that.

First, select the list itself and access its properties. Click on the ellipses (...) button to access the property dialog:

[image]

Clear out the *Specified text* field so that no content is rendered when no rows are returned.

[image]